# I am trying to create a producer for AWS MSK using Springboot app, able to create it from EC2 client(Using kafka-console-producer.sh)

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker, apache-kafka, aws-msk

while producing message to msk(kafka 2.1.0) I am getting

> "Exception thrown when sending a message with `key='null'` and `payload='Message->0'` to topic AWSKafkaTopic"

I am trying to produce it from a springboot app deployed on EC2 using docker.
But the producer is working fine when I am trying to produce the message from same EC2 client using kafka-console-producer.sh.

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list "XXBootstrapBrokerStringTlsXX" --producer.config client.properties --topic AWSKafkaTopic
```

I have tried the same program on my local with kafka 2.3.0 and zookeeper, it is working fine there(running springboot app on docker).

```
Config-> 
    @Value("${spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers}")
        private String bootstrapServers;

        @Bean
        public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,bootstrapServers);    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class);        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringSerializer.class);
            return props;
        }

        @Bean
        public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
            return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
        }

        @Bean
        public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
            return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
        }

        @Bean
        public Sender sender() {
            return new Sender();
        }


Client->
     @Autowired
        private KafkaTemplate<String,String> kafkaTemplate;

        public void sendMessage(String message){
            this.kafkaTemplate.send("AWSKafkaTopic",message);
        }

Actual result->

    ProducerConfig values:
            acks = 1
            batch.size = 16384
            bootstrap.servers = [XXBootstrapBrokerStringTlsXX]
            buffer.memory = 33554432
            client.id =
            compression.type = none
            connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
            enable.idempotence = false
            interceptor.classes = []
            key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
            linger.ms = 0
            max.block.ms = 60000
            max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
            max.request.size = 1048576
            metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
            metric.reporters = []
            metrics.num.samples = 2
            metrics.recording.level = INFO
            metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
            partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
            receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
            reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
            reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
            request.timeout.ms = 30000
            retries = 0
            retry.backoff.ms = 100
            sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
            sasl.jaas.config = null
            sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
            sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
            sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
            sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
            sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
            sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
            sasl.login.class = null
            sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
            sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
            sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
            sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
            sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
            security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
            send.buffer.bytes = 131072
            ssl.cipher.suites = null
            ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
            ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
            ssl.key.password = null
            ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
            ssl.keystore.location = null
            ssl.keystore.password = null
            ssl.keystore.type = JKS
            ssl.protocol = TLS
            ssl.provider = null
            ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
            ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
            ssl.truststore.location = null
            ssl.truststore.password = null
            ssl.truststore.type = JKS
            transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
            transactional.id = null
            value.serializer = class
value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Log:

```
2019-07-24 07:40:43.305  INFO 1 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version : 2.0.1
2019-07-24 07:40:43.305  INFO 1 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId : fa14705e51bd2ce5
2019-07-24 07:41:43.313 ERROR 1 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.s.k.support.LoggingProducerListener    : Exception thrown when sending a message with key='null' and payload='Message->0' to topic AWSKafkaTopic:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.
```

Comment: I have tried to produce and consume messages with kafka 2.1.0 on my local its working fine with this version. Could anyone please help me to identify where i am missing the things or i need to try some other approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please configure your logs to `DEBUG`-level and check if any exception is provided (some exceptions are logged at `DEBUG` level by a producer). Also, are you sure the security protocol is correctly configured for your producer? Especially, you need to specify the property `security.protocol` and set it to `SSL`, or the client defaults to plaintext communication.

Comment: The problem was with the security configurations, for AWS MSK we need to provide ssl security details to our configurations and that we can add in prop map itself.
The problem is solved and it's working as expected now.

Comment: Hi Mukulit can you provide details on how you fixed it?

Comment: @AashishKatta 
we need to create truststore,jks file and package it with our project also need to pass the path of that file in the property map.

Comment: @MukulitBhati I'm also using the same code but I'm not able to connect with aws-msk . Any more configs you have added ? . I'm getting Broker not avaiable exception

Answer (score 0):

In my case i tried to produce the message in new topic but `auto.create.topics.enable` was `false` in the aws broker so better to create a message on existing topic or `auto.create.topics.enable` set this property as `true` and try.